Solve the congruence $x^{11}+y^{16}\equiv 2013 \pmod{199}$
I was trying to solve the congruence equation  $x^{11}+y^{16}\equiv 2013 \pmod{199}$. I know $199$ is a prime and that $199\equiv 1 \pmod{11}$ and hence not every number is an 11-th power and thus the equation is not trivial to solve. Is there any fast way/ smart way to solve this equation instead of plugging in small number one by one to check? Thanks.

Reminding $199-1=11\cdot18$ may be helpful w/ Fermat’s little thm… but didn’t try a lot with this ;)

@lulu sorry i meant to say $199\equiv 1 \pmod{11}$, I edited my question.

Yes, that one works.

The possible values for $y^{16}$ is the perfect squares modulo $199.$ I don't think there is much you can do but brute force after that.

Note first that $\ y^{16}\ $ is a quadratic residue mod $199$, so the congruence can't have a solution for $\ y\ $ unless $\ 2013-x^{11}\ $ is such a quadratic residue.  On the other hand, if $\ 2013-x^{11}\ $ is a quadratic residue mod $199$ then there must be a primitive element $\ \pi\ $ of the group of units of $\ \Bbb{Z}/199\Bbb{Z}\ $ under multiplication, and a positive integer $\ k\ $ between $2$ and $99$, such that $\ \pi^{2k}\equiv2013-x^{11}\pmod{199}\ .$ If we now set $\ r\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}8^{-1}k\pmod{99}\ ,$ then
\begin{align}
8r&\equiv k\pmod{99}\ ,\\
16r&\equiv2k\pmod{198}\ ,\ \text{and therefore}\\
\pi^{16r}&\equiv\pi^{2k}\pmod{199}\\
&\equiv2013-x^{11}\pmod{199}\ ,
\end{align}
so we could choose $\ \pi^r\ $ for $\ y\ .$ For $\ x=1,2,3,4\ ,$ we find that $\ \big(2013-x^{11}\big)^{99}\equiv198\pmod{199}\ ,$ so $\ 2013-x^{11}\ $ isn't a quadratic residue mod $199$ for any of those values of $\ x\ .$ As a bonus, we've found that $\ (2013-1)^{99}\equiv$$\,22^{99}\equiv$$\,198\pmod{199}\ ,$ and hence $\ 22\ $ is a primitive element of the multiplicative group of units of $\ \Bbb{Z}/199\Bbb{Z}\ .$
On the other hand $\ \big(2013-5^{11}\big)^{99}\equiv$$\,130^{99}\equiv$$\,1$$\pmod{199}\ ,$ so $\ 2013-5^{11}\equiv130\pmod{199}\ $ is a quadratic residue mod $199$, and $\ 130\equiv$$\,22^{188}\equiv$$\,22^{2\cdot94}\pmod{199}\ .$ Now $\ 8^{-1}\cdot94\equiv4^{-1}\cdot47\equiv$$\,25\cdot47\equiv86\pmod{99}\ .$ Therefore, one solution to the congruence is $\ x=5\ $ and $\ y\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}22^{86}\pmod{199}=46\ ,$ which can be checked with Wolfram alpha or any other sufficiently capable computer algebra package.
Update
In starting my search for quadratic residues mod $199$ of the form $\ 2013-x^{11}\ $ at $\ x=1\ $ I was inadvertently rejecting solutions with $\ x=0\ .$ Since $\ 2013\equiv23\equiv22^{40}\equiv22^{2\cdot20}$$\,\pmod{199}\ ,$
however, $2013$ is a quadratic residue mod $199$, and solutions with $\ x=0\ $ do exist.  Since $\ 8^{-1}20\equiv$$\,2^{-1}5\equiv$$\,50\cdot5\equiv$$\,52$$\,\pmod{99}\ ,$ then $\ x=0\ $ and $\ y\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}$$\,22^{52}\equiv$$\,104\pmod{199}\ $ is a solution to the congruence, which again checks out in Wolfram alpha.
